# Python - mean value outside of a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 NumPy array as follow:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8])
b = np.array([2, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 4, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 7, 2, 1, 1, 9, 9])
```

and 2 constant numbers:

```
c = 6
d = 3
```

I extract an array out of array `a` each time:

- elements in `a` are less than `c`, more than 2 times consecutively,
- and elements in `b` are less than `d`, more than 2 times consecutively.

For that I use the following code:

```
mask = ~((a < c) & (b < d))
split_indices = np.where(mask)[0]
for subarray in np.split(a, split_indices + 1):
    if len(subarray) > 2:
        x=(subarray[:-1])
        print(x)
```

Now I need to calculate each times my conditions are meet, the cumulative sum of `a - x`. For that I just added in the last `if` loop the following code:

```
xx = np.cumsum(sum(c) - x))
```

which output `13` and `7`

My problem is that I need to know the mean value of all the `xx`. So with this minimal example the result value will be `10`. If I put the command `np.mean(xx)` inside or even outside of the loop it will just calculate the mean of the last `xx` value and not the mean value of each time `xx` that were calculated in the loop. Does anyone knows how to achieve that?

Comment: you can keep appending `mean(x)` inside loop to some list. Wont that work in your case.

Comment: @Poojan - it might work but I dont really know how to do that

Comment: Check the answer is that something you are looking for?

Comment: i dont understand you `np.cumsum(sum(c) - x))` part but hoping equation correct from your part, using list you can keep trace of each cumsum.

Comment: @poojan - I need to fix that first now :) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable I

Comment: Yes because sum(c) does not look correct way to go. because c is just a number not a list.

Comment: @Poojan Thanks! the sum component was not necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = []
mask = ~((a < c) & (b < d))
split_indices = np.where(mask)[0]
for subarray in np.split(a, split_indices + 1):
    if len(subarray) > 2:
        x=(subarray[:-1])
        l.append(np.cumsum(sum(c) - x)))
        print(x)
print(np.mean(l))
```